# Add &nbsp; in between <p></p>

Tags: jquery

![enter image description here][1]![enter image description here][2]here we need to check using jquery.

if `<p></p>` is empty, have to add `&nbsp;` in between to create some space. is it possible to do in jquery?

Also, if text content is 1 line, add some padding. if its 2 line, add some more padding. is it possible to do dynamically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
    var p = $('p');
    p.each(function(){        
      if($(this).is(':empty')){
        $(this).html('&nbsp;');
      }
    });
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oap3kvLc/2/)

---

To add paddings:

```
if(p.height() < 10){
  p.css('padding','10px');
}
```

Comment: It's wrong. p.length returned length of array of p tags on page

Comment: and you need to use .html(), not .text()

Comment: Hi.. Need your help to solve this issue.. Please check image 1 & image 2. Image 1 & 2 white transparent height have to be same on load. if its 1 line of text, have to add padding-bottom to fit like 2 lines. Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: Your question is totally different than previous. Don't do that. This will hamper for future users. Please ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks... will create new question.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
$('p:empty').html('&nbsp');
```

Answer (score 1):

use [jQuery.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/), as:

```
if ($('#your-p-selector').is(':empty')) { 
    $('#your-p-selector').html('&nbsp');  
}
```

**Note::** this does not provide complete solution, but is an indication of how one can check for empty elements using jQuery.

Comment: It's wrong. Please, see http://jsfiddle.net/oap3kvLc/3/. You need to use .each() or other loop

Comment: @magmel No, its not. See here:: http://jsfiddle.net/oap3kvLc/4/ See that i am using id selector, its just an example of how to check for empty elements..!

Comment: It's id-selector, only one per page. This question was about all p tags on page.

Comment: @magmel i dont see anything like that in question.. "if <p></p> is empty...", does not mean "all p tags", and btw, the answer indicates how it needs to be done (check for emptiness in this case)...!

Comment: Ok, you are right. But you need to write about it in your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    var p = $('p');
    p.each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().length < 1) {
            $(this).html('&nbsp;');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Magmel,Thanks.. i embed below code on our server. still its not adding "&nbsp;". We have multiple "isotope-title" li to display contents dynamically. content will have <h1><p> tags.. if any of content with<p></p>.. have to add "&nbsp;" in between.

var p = $('.isotope-tile .content p');
    p.each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().length < 1) {
            $(this).html('&nbsp;');
        }
    });

Comment: Ok. Glad to see your success after our answers :)

Comment: Hi.. Need your help to solve this issue.. Please check image 1 & image 2. Image 1 & 2 white transparent height have to be same on load. if its 1 line of text, have to add padding-bottom to fit like 2 lines. Is it possible? Thanks